# Is the language $\{ 0^m10^n \mid m,n\geq1 \}$ regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

$L = \{ 0^m10^n|m\geq1 \wedge n\geq1 \}$
Is this a regular language?

A language is regular when there is a DFA accepting the language. Since there is a DFA accepting this language I suppose that it is a regular language. But as I have seen in the book it says that it is not regular. So I am confused. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: This language is indeed regular. This is corresponding regular expression $0^+10^+$. Which book?

Comment: The language $\{0^n10^n|n\geq1\}$ isn't regular, but your language is.